# for http request to google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoding-api, http-request

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=(API_KEY)

Google API page said the above URL is the http request and a json string is the response.  How do I 
do this in javascript? I tried using the XMLHTTPrequest object at first but later found out it doesn't work between different domains. I then tried using a callback function with

where 
 function myCallbackFunction(expectedJSONstring){
alert(expectedJSONstring)
}
doesn't get called.

Comment: If you want to do this from javascript, why aren't you using the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to do this is in JavaScript is through the [Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) that geocodezip mentioned. The main reason for doing this is that quota becomes per-user rather than per-key.

If you still want to do this through JavaScript then something like jQuery's [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) will do cross-domain requests of JSON payloads.

You really should use the Geocoding service though. It's much nicer. Really. Go on. Use it.